# module 'shapely' has no attribute 'geometry' when using Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am using geopandas for some spatial analysis and am running into an error when using the points_from_xy function. I have the following line of code:

```py
MW = gp.GeoDataFrame(mw_coordinates,
  geometry=gp.points_from_xy(x=mw_coordinates['x'], 
    y=mw_coordinates['y'], crs=crs))
```

Which results in this error:

`AttributeError: module 'shapely' has no attribute 'geometry'`

I am using MacOS and installed Geopandas with all dependencies via Conda Forge, and the following command **does work** to import geometry from Shapely manually:

`import shapely.geometry`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you on, Windows? There are issues with installing Geopandas on Windows, if that is your OS then I will show you the link to install it properly without errors

Comment: Geopandas requires a very involved installation for use on Windows OS, this guide is courtesy of [Geoff Boeing (external link)](https://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/). You need to change environment variables etc, manually install Fiona etc for Geopandas to work correctly, pip install and other methods do not work all the time for Windows. "First and most important: do not try to directly pip install or conda install any of the dependencies – if you do, they will fail in some way later, often silently or obscurely, making troubleshooting difficult."

Comment: I am on an M1 Mac, I'll edit my original question to reflect that

Comment: Here is link https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/

Comment: what is `mw_coordinates`? and how have you imported `gp` ? need a more complete code sample to be able to help

Answer (score 1):

As per comment,  without a full minimum example it's not possible to resolve your error.  Have synthesized this.

- Does it work?
- It is not clear what `mw_coordinates` is.  It looks like a **dataframe**, could be a **dict**
- from the error it's not immediately clear it's an installation issue

```
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd

mw_coordinates = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["name", "x", "y"],
    data=[
        ["Tegucigalpa", -87.2194751979415, 14.103990759076396],
        ["Belmopan", -88.76707299981655, 17.252033507246892],
        ["Podgorica", 19.266306924118226, 42.465972512881706],
        ["Gaborone", 25.91194779328538, -24.646313457438907],
        ["Male", 73.499947467955, 4.1667081898118],
        ["Juba", 31.580025592787308, 4.829975198277964],
        ["Sao Tome", 6.733325153234773, 0.3334021188329075],
        ["Bern", 7.466975462482424, 46.91668275866772],
        ["Paramaribo", -55.16703088542437, 5.835030129922586],
        ["San Marino", 12.441770157800141, 43.936095834768004],
    ],
)
crs = "epsg:4386"
MW = gp.GeoDataFrame(
    mw_coordinates,
    geometry=gp.points_from_xy(x=mw_coordinates["x"], y=mw_coordinates["y"], crs=crs),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the responses. I was able to resolve this error by starting over in a new conda environment and reinstalling Geopandas from conda forge. I am not sure what the cause was initially as I was also in a fresh environment when I ran into it.

In response to Rob, mw_coordinates is a DataFrame with well names and x-y-z corrdinates:

```
MW             x              y          z
1.0   1.948293e+06  625635.615173  20.027135
2.0   1.948294e+06  625479.944974  19.999499
3.0   1.948294e+06  625295.156011  19.959875
4.0   1.948134e+06  625177.900975  19.438464
5.0   1.948135e+06  625053.886085  19.554898
6.0   1.947928e+06  625486.354308  19.891194
7.0   1.947928e+06  625388.739060  19.841715
8.0   1.947928e+06  625290.605652  19.962517
9.0   1.947907e+06  625147.859278  19.431860
10.0  1.947907e+06  625052.148115  19.435924
11.0  1.947704e+06  625516.932454  19.277022
12.0  1.947705e+06  625407.428177  19.268081
13.0  1.947699e+06  625296.353875  19.280984
14.0  1.947697e+06  625149.441190  19.254162
15.0  1.947701e+06  625031.845387  19.125739
16.0  1.947526e+06  625516.064688  19.326399
17.0  1.947527e+06  625406.695742  19.288706
18.0  1.947537e+06  625295.598276  19.107959
19.0  1.947529e+06  625148.770325  19.064983
20.0  1.947533e+06  625030.705130  19.097495
```

With crs equal to the following:

```
crs = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=37.06666666666667 +lat_2=38.43333333333333   +lat_0=36.5 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000.0000000002 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs"
```

And geopandas imported via:

```
import geopandas as gp
```